# How to save java source code in an xml file, and edit/compile it in an IDE?

Tags: java, xml, compilation, save

We have an java application in which the user can write/execute their own java code and use imports from compiled jars - i.e. they write it, and it is compiled and run by the application. They can also save this code (along with various other information that they are using) - currently this is saved to a human-readable xml file.

I want to be able to use those save xml files in an IDE (principally, Intellij), so that if the user changes things in their compiled jar in the IDE, these changes can also be picked up in the save xml file.

For example, if a save file used a class from the compiled jar, it may have the following import:

```
import com.company.project.package.subpackage.MyClass;
```

Let's say that class was moved, so the import was:

```
import com.company.project.package.subpackage.subsub.MyClass;
```

...this would change all the save xml files that used that class and import - just as the IDE would for all the other usages in the compiled project.

(This, and other examples, arises because the compiled jar is both constantly in development and in use using the aforementioned application.)

At the moment, if I were to add the save xml files to a sub-project in the IDE, the user can edit the save files manually, possibly taking advantage of 'find/replace' or 'search for usage in text' functions. This is better than nothing, but still a rather involved/complicated process. Also, there is no checking that the code in the save files are consistent with the code in the compiled project.

One approach that I am considering is a script or a test class that would unpack the save xml file, writing the java code to java files, and then try and compile (and possibly running/testing) those java files.

A further step would be to write a maven plugin (we use maven for our build cycle) or an ant script (ant still has its uses...) to do this, and possibly make this part of our build process - i.e. you cannot compile the project without ensuring all of the save xml files in its sub-project also compile.

- Does this seem like a reasonable approach?
- Are there alternative approaches that anyone could suggest?

Comment: Can't they save their java source code in a, you know, `.java` source code file? Why XML?

Comment: Because, as my question states, it's being saved along with various other information. I considered the possibility of two save files (i.e. one for code, one for other stuff...) but I determined that the danger of those getting mismatched/corrupted etc. was too great.

Comment: You could use custom annotations within the javadoc of the source file's header, to keep everything in one place. Depends how complicated your metadata is.

Comment: It's pretty complicated - the java code is a fraction of the application save file. I'm confident that saving as a .java file is not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: *"I'm confident that saving as a .java file is not the solution I'm looking for."* Save it as a Zip with 1 (or more) XML files as well as any source (in paths according to package) that is required.  This has the twin advantage of allowing source to be a different encoding to the XML, as well as consolidating all the necessary parts of the project.  You could even include other files easily, a manifest, help files etc.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - that's an interesting approach, but I'd really prefer to stick to the single save file approach outlined above.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - I've given your suggestion some further thought and and am going to have a go at implementing it. Can you post it as an answer, so I can up-vote it (and, possibly, accept it)?

Comment: Comment upgraded to answer.  :)

Answer (score 3):

> ..saving as a .java file is not the solution I'm looking for.

Save it as a Zip with 1 (or more) XML files as well as any source (in paths according to package) that is required. You could even include other files easily, a manifest, help files etc.

This has a number of advantages:

- It allows source & include files to be a different encoding to the XML
- It consolidates all the necessary parts of the project into one file, without any 'jumping though hoops' to make one format fit inside another.
- It allows different compression levels as appropriate to the data (e.g. text/XML compresses well, whereas a serialized image does not).

Comment: *"and comment on how it went..."*  I look forward to reading your report.  :)

Comment: So.. how'd it go?