# How can I add an image to a CSV file?

Tags: java, image, csv

I need to write an image on a .csv file with some data. Writing data was simple but I cant write an image into it which is stored on the hard disk. I am using `FileWriter` class to implement this and `.append();` to add items in the file. How can I add an image to a CSV file?

Comment: Binary data is no good fit for CSV. You could Base64 encode it, but it would still be very large, so not all tools that can handle CSV may be too happy about it. Maybe just put the file name (or path) for the image into the CSV?

Comment: What is your use case? Maybe CSV file is not the best storage. If you need do keep data - use database. If you'er creating a spreadsheet for excel - use Apache POI and XLS format. That will let you add images.

Comment: Piotr Gwiazda, my case is that i have to print(on paper), Tags which contain the following information: Barcode(in .png form), Product name, Price, Seller etc. Have you any better idea by which i can achieve this task rather than exporting and printing to to a .csv file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments, you'd be better off storing a text representation of your barcode (along with the other information, such as product name, price, etc) in the CSV file (instead of embedding the image or filename).

Then when reading the CSV file, you can use an open source library such as [Barbecue](http://barbecue.sourceforge.net) to dynamically generate the barcode image. Barbecue supports a wide range of barcode and image formats.

Answer (score 11):

CSV is a text based file format, where as an images are binary data, the two don't mix well.

You'd be better of supplying a reference to the images (relative path and name) and bundling them together.

Comment: You might use a Zip file as [discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12910963/418556) to incorporate the CSV & images.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Indeed, that would make a nice bundle ;)

Comment: couldn't  do it, any other options?

Comment: Andrew Thompson, the link you gave how can i use it make my images to be exported to a csv file?

Comment: @user1690481 It doesn't and it can't.  Andrew is suggesting that you bundle the images and CSV files together in a Zip file (much like a Word docx file)

Comment: Bite the bullet. You aren't going to be able to "embed" an image inside the CSV file. You best bet is to, as Andrew has suggested, link the image file to the CSV file by placing the image name inside the CSV and bundle the files together in something like a zip file.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Storing a reference to the image file and bundling it would work, but isn't it far simpler to store the text representation of the barcode (probably a product id in this case), and generate the image when reading the CSV file? See my answer...